# In Meteor how to render the templates on server side?

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, handlebars.js

I followed [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/whats-this-meteor-thing/) and I built this with it: http://x111.meteor.com/
But as you can see the loading is very slow, because meteor loads the data from client side.

I get this error when I want to use the global `Template` inside `Meteor.isServer`:

```
ReferenceError: Template is not defined
at app/products.js:56:3 ...
```

How do I serve the templates from server side so I don't have to wait for the client?

Comment: The *whole point* of Meteor is *data on the wire* - don't serve HTMl, serve data

Answer (score 6):

Try [this](https://github.com/EventedMind/meteor-handlebars-server).
This package adds support for server side Handlebars in Meteor. It's primarily intended as a stop gap for server side email html until Meteor releases server side rendering support.

```
> mrt add handlebars-server
```

Answer (score 1):

The templates are served up with the server even though the code is in the client html. The reason they take long is the step for the meteor collections to download to the client on the first load.

Update: I know this isn't what you asked for exactly, but the root cause of the lag isn't the Templating system.

The core issue would be the **latency between your browser & the server**. You need to place the server closer to you to remove this lag / make it shorter as would be with any web server.

If you can't get a server closer you could display a *loading...* message so users are aware the data will be available shortly.

```
{{#unless CartItems.count}}
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">Loading...</td>
    </tr>
{{else}}
    {{#each CartItems}} 
        <tr>
           <td>{{Name}}</td>
           <td>${{Price}}</td>
           <td>{{Quantity}}</td>
           <td>${{Total}}</td>
        </tr>
     {{/each}}
{{/unless}}
```

Comment: Really? I mean this should be basic in a server.. lol :D Serving dynamic pages is way more important in most cases than updating the pages.

Comment: you should not be loading all the data client side. it should be paged in for what you need for a given template. This can be restricted by your server-side publish function.

Comment: He only has 3 entries of data, I think its a latency thing between the server and browser. @Adam If you run this on your localhost do you get the same issue?

Comment: It is not a distance problem, it is clear that the informations are called using xhr requests, because if I turn off javascript nothing is displayed. Yes I have the same issue locally.

Comment: Thats a bit irregular, usually the lag is unnoticable < 100ms, could you post your code up?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no built-in way to do this, but adding serverside template rendering is a planned feature (though I don't see it on the Roadmap yet):

> This version of spiderable is specifically for search engines. A
>   future version of Meteor will also send HTML to web browsers on inital
>   page load. The Meteor templating system was designed specifically to
>   support this use case.

(http://meteor.com/faq/can-meteor-serve-static-html)

While people will say this violates the "only send data over the wire" philosophy, for sites that need good SEO it's pretty necessary, and also a very natural thing to do when you have the same template language and framework available to both the server and client.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for this type of functionality in a Node.JS framework I would recommend using Derby.JS http://derbyjs.com/

Comment: but this question about meteorjs!